# Transfer Groovy script response to properties in SOAP UI 5.21

Tags: groovy, soapui

Can any one know how to transfer the groovyscript response into the properties step of SOAP UI. I am trying to generate the random numbers using the groovy script, and when i am gettign the random generated numbers how do i transfer that value to properties in soap ui which can be used for the TCs as a parametered value.

TIA

Comment: please try to formulate your question in a way that makes it easier to understand. Maybe with example code?

Answer (score 2):

To make it simple,

Use below code to store any value on,

- test case level custom properties:

> testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("propertyName","value");

- test suite level custom properties:

> testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("propertyName","value");

- project level custom properties:

> testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("propertyName","value");

Use below code to check whether value stored successfully on runtime:

- test case level:

> log.info testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("propertyName");

- test suite level:

> log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("propertyName");

- project level:

> log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("propertyName");

Use below code to use the property value inside anywhere on,

- test case level:

> ${#TestCase#propertyName}

- test suite level:

> ${#TestSuite#propertyName}

- project level:

> ${#Project#propertyName}

- global level:

> ${#Global#propertyName}

Comment: Thanks Shiyam.. will surely make use of the above code when required  :)

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go:**

The below groovy script code snippet will generate a random number and set the value into to a test case level custom property, say `PROPERTY_NAME`.

*Groovy Script*

```
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('PROPERTY_NAME', (Math.abs(new Random().nextInt()) + 1).toString())
```

In the same test case, it can be accessed in any test requests as  `${#TestCase#PROPERTY_NAME}`

**EDIT:** Based on the change you wanted while above original code works though

```
def a = 9 
def AccountName = ''
(0..a).each {  AccountName = AccountName + new Random().nextInt(a) } 
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('Property_Name', AccountName.toString())
```

Even you achieve the same thing using below (just updated value in **nextInt()** to the first answer)

```
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('PROPERTY_NAME', (Math.abs(new Random().nextInt(999999998)) + 1).toString())
```

Comment: Hi Rao,  thanks for the reply.. I am using the below code to generate the random numbers int a = 9
AccountName = ""
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
 random = new Random()
 randomInteger= random.nextInt(a)
 AccountName = AccountName + randomInteger
}

log.info AccountName..                ---- now i need to pass the AccountName value what i get into a property step.. where i have given the variable same as AccountName. Since i am working for RESTFUL i need to pass this random generated value in a header...

Comment: @Sandeep, can you update the question then with your code?

Comment: @Sandeep, you may use all the code that you needed and finally use above mentioned line of code and replace right most value. In the rest step use the above mentioned value `${#TestCase#PROPERTY_NAME}` where it is required

Comment: As per ur valuable feedback i passed the ${#TestCase#Property_Name} in the header where i wanted the value to be populated. BUt it is taking the value "${#TestCase#Property_Name}", its not taking the random number which is being generated :( :(

Comment: No, that does not seem to be correct or may be something wrong. You can see it in action, see in the attachment (notice the numbers sequence of steps) http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03168675883308633625

Comment: @Sandeep, can you update the question with script that you are trying? Also check what value is set to the property when run the groovy script?

Comment: This is the script wht i am using to generate the random numbers in SOAP UI, int a = 9
AccountName = ""
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
 random = new Random()
 randomInteger= random.nextInt(a)
 AccountName = AccountName + randomInteger
}

log.info AccountName  -------- here its generating 9 digit value as needed. Now i need to pass the generated value waht we get in the log output to the properties. As of now its just taking the blank value....

Comment: Because, you have not added the above line at the end and replace your value given in the answer(which i already mentioned in earlier comments). Did you at least try what has been given to you? what happens you will come to know? And later you can update it with you additional changes.

Comment: Sorry bro, i had missed a delimiter there so it was not working fine.. i had used the set.property what u had gven earlier also. but there was copy paste error which was not working... But now its working fine.. :) thanks a ton :)

Comment: ya rao, asper your comments only i tried, and its working now.. thanks.. that reply wa for you only :)

Comment: @Sandeep, I believe it answered your question, would you mind accepting it as answer?